# Map is not mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Hi I am trying to update my array using map function following this example:

```
var arr = ["1", 2, 3, 4];
arr = arr.map(function(v) {
  return "foo"+ v;
});
```

but in my code it is not updating, my code looks something like

```
obj['payment_info'].forEach(function(info) {
    info['method'].map(function(method) {
       return '';
    });
});
```

Comment: yaa your obj and info objects too

Comment: You aren't doing an assignment in your loop

Comment: @Daniel can you explain what do you mean by assignment ?

Comment: See Adam's answer

Comment: oh man I always forget this, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Array#map` must be assigned to the old variable

```
obj['payment_info'].forEach(function(info) {
    info['method'] = info['method'].map(function(method) {
       return '';
    });
});
```

Here's a small test case with:

```js
var arr = ["1", 2, 3, 4];
arr.map(function(v) {
  return "foo"+ v;
});
console.log(arr); // Output ["1", 2, 3, 4];

arr = arr.map(function(v) {
  return "foo"+ v;
});
console.log(arr); // Output ["foo1", "foo2", "foo3","foo4"];
```